# request.getSession(true) ALWAYS returns a new session when client = android

Tags: java, android, servlets

I'm writing a servlet that handles requests from android clients. Each time I'm performing a HttpGet the servlet assigns a sessionID based on the result of `HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);`.

The problem is that at each request the `request.getSession(true);` always assigns a new session value. Even when the request comes from the same client the `.getSession(true)` returns a new sessionID ONLY if there's no existing session. Also when testing if the `HttpSession` is new with a condition `if (session.isNew()) { // do something }` it's always true even if the request comes from the same client. When executing the same URL from a browser all is fine.

If the session is NEVER recognized as being old, I have no practical way to set a lease(expiration) time for my session.

**The code, Android side:**

```
private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

        private String URL = "http://server:port/path/servlet?";
        private String functionType = "function=";
        private String statement = "&statement=";
        private String text = "&text=";
        private String language = "&language=";

        protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
           InputStream in = entity.getContent();
             StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
             int n = 1;
             while (n > 0) {
                 byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                 n =  in.read(b);
                 if (n > 0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
             }
             return out.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {

             String command = params[0];

             HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();         

             HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL + command);
             System.out.println("Sent URL: " + URL + command);

             String text = null;
             try {
                   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                   text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity).toString();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 return e.getLocalizedMessage();
             }
             return text;
        }
    }
```

**The code, Servlet side:**

```
protected JSONObject validateID(HttpServletRequest request, JSONObject JSONObj, String lang) throws JSONException, SQLException {

        // Get the current session object, create one if new 
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        boolean validID = request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();

        System.out.println("sessionID is valid : " + validID);
        Date daysAgo = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10 * 1000);
        Date created = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
        long sessionAge = (System.currentTimeMillis() - created.getTime());
        System.out.println("sessionAge : " + sessionAge);

        // In case of relogin without logout
        if (!session.isNew() && lastID != null) {
            System.out.println("sessionID is " + sessionAge + "ms OLD... received ID : " + lastID);

            if (lastID.equals(lastID)) {
            JSONObj.remove("LoggedIn");
            JSONObj.put("LoggedIn", lastID); // already LoggedIn with this sessionID
            } else {
                JSONObj.remove("LoggedIn");
                JSONObj.put("LoggedIn", "Invalid"); // corrupted sessionID
            }
        } 

        // Invalidating a session if it's older than 24h
        if (!session.isNew()) {  // skip new sessions

              if (created.before(daysAgo)) {
                session.invalidate();
                System.out.println("sessionID EXPIRED... invalidating ID : " + lastID);

                languageConns.remove(lastID);
                connections.remove(lastID);
                lastID = null;
                JSONObj.put("LoggedIn", "Expired"); //if sessionID expired
              }
        } else if (session.isNew()) {
            session = request.getSession(false);  //get a new session
            lastID = session.getId();
            System.out.println("sessionID is NEW or INVALID... generated ID : " + lastID);

            JSONObj.remove("LoggedIn");
            JSONObj.put("LoggedIn", lastID); // return a secure sessionID

            connections.remove(lastID);
            connections.put(lastID, conn);

            languageConns.remove(lastID);
            languageConns.put(lastID, lang);

            System.out.println("languageConns : " + languageConns);
            System.out.println("connections : " + connections);
        } 

        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(86400);
        System.out.println("JSONObj after validatingID : " + JSONObj);
        return JSONObj;
    }
```

**QUESTION:**

What, in this code, could cause a sessionID to be recognized only as new when the request comes from an android client but the same request performs as expected when running it in a browser?

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: You have to store the cookies from the first request, and send it in the headers of the following requests.

Comment: I'm not using cookies for retaining state. It's a URL rewriting strategy. In either case a visit/request from the same client, with or without cookies, SHOULD BE identified as having the same sessionID when running a session.isNew()

Comment: Then, where in the code do you add the jsessionid to the URL, so that the server know which session the request is part of? If you don't send any cookie, nor rewrite the URL, obviously, the server can't magicall know what the session ID is.

Comment: Indeed, discard my first comment. Do you have any resources at hand(or code snippet) that makes use of URL rewriting in order to track sessions?

Comment: I'd use cookies instead, but you can simply append ;jsessionid=<session_id> at the end of the URL (before the query string). See section 7.1.3 of the [servlet 3.0 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/).

Comment: So this: http://server:port/path/servlet? should be this: http://server:port/path/servlet:jsessionid=<session.getId()>? where session.getId returns the session String?

Comment: use response.encodeURL() instead of doing it manually.